# Python 3.6: How to save file with unicode/utf-8 filename?

Tags: python, unicode, flask

So I'm having trouble to write a file upload in flask that writes unicode filenames.

Here is what I have:

```
   for name, file in request.files.items():

        if secure_filename(file.filename) in alternate_file_index: 

            path_to_save = "/test-unicode/B-286_10 - \u8907\u88fd.xls"

            # file.save(path_to_save) didnt work

            with open(path_to_save, "wb") as save_file:
                save_file.write(file.read())
        else:
            # English name files
            path_to_save = "path/to/save"
            file.save(path_to_save)
```

Error:

if I use path_to_save.encode("utf-8"), I get:

```
    fdst.write(buf)
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'write'
```

file.save(path_to_save) gives this error:

```
 File "/flaskapp/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/datastructures.py", line 2703, in save
    dst = open(dst, 'wb')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 54-55: ordinal not in range(128)
```

All the cases in english characters works great.

Any advice would be appreciated. Ty.

Answer:
After posting this questions on stackoverflow, the bug has been magically solved.

PS:
path_to_save.encode("utf-8") works. Apparently, I missed that moment when the program runs. LOLZ...

Comment: try to add .decode('utf-8')

Comment: path_to_save = path_to_save.decode('utf-8')
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

Comment: That's `encode`, not `decode`.

Comment: `save_file.write(data.encode('utf-8'))`. You are trying to write `str` to a file object that expects bytes.

Comment: Your  `AttributeError` is just an error on your part; `fdst` is a bytes object, not the file object. Did you want to call `save_file.write(buf)` instead?

Comment: What is `data` that you're using?

Comment: Your `UnicodeEncodeError` exception otherwise makes no sense. Please provide a proper [mcve] with full traceback that shows how you got to that exception.

Comment: I should revise my question, because the data object is a file object that I didn't expect to matter. I think I'm not writing binaries. And I got similar situation when writing ascii filename to disk.

Comment: @tipsywacky: most of all, there is no explicit encoding in the code you posted, so what is actually throwing that exception?

Comment: On top of all that, you are mixing up slashes and backslashes in your path... That's to be avoided, I guess.

Comment: @nostradamus the backslashes like \u88fd is the start of ascii code I think. not the folder path slashes.

Comment: @tipsywacky Oh, alright, I see... Thanks for the hint. But can this work at all?! I'll follow the discussion, hoping for a personal surprise. ;)

Comment: @nostradamus prolly not, lolz. Maybe I will try turning the file into binaries first and hopefully will be able to post the solution :P.

Comment: @nostradamus OMG!

Comment: Add `.encode('utf-8')` to filename. Did the work for me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the arg "encoding = 'utf-8'"

```
  with open(path_to_save, "wb", encoding="utf-8") as save_file:
        save_file.write(data)
```

Comment: Please read the question , it is clearly mentioned Python 3.6 and dont down vote unneccessarily

Comment: It's already binary mode, so we won't be passing str here. Hence encoding doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Also, the exception posted makes 0 sense in Python 3 where there is no implicit encoding, but then again they also have an exception about `bytes` not having an attribute, which only can mean Python 3.